# Compilation error GNU Fortran - finalization

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, finalization

I am trying to compile a large code in using GNU compiler.
However, when I try to compile the attached piece of code with GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.1.0, some routines using type `fn_grid_nodes_t` throw this error message:

> @bld .. linking,  ...
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "___final_fn_core_grids_dts_Fn_grid_nodes_t.3665", referenced from:
>         ___fn_depot_utils_MOD_fn_clean_depot in fn_depot_utils.o

Note that using Intel compiler > 15.0, the compilation is successful.
I suspect it is due to how GNU and Intel handle finalization.

Does anyone have any suggestion/workaround about this?

```
type :: fn_grid_nodes_t

    ! mpi communicator
    type(fmpi_fcomm_t) :: fcomm

    ! grid description
    type(fn_grid_descrp_t) :: grid_descrp

    ! grid partition description
    type(fn_parts_descrp_t) :: parts_descrp

    ! node hdr plan
    type(fn_node_hdr_plan_t) :: node_hdr_plan

    ! node elem plan
    type(fn_node_elem_plan_t) :: node_elem_plan

    ! exchanger
    type(fn_exchr_t) :: exchr_nghb

    ! active node count
    integer(kp_i) :: active_ncnt = -1_kp_i

    ! dynamic node array
    type(fn_node_t),allocatable :: nodes(:)

    ! auxiliary
    real(kp_r),allocatable :: aux_block(:,:,:,:)

  end type fn_grid_nodes_t
```

Thanks for your answers - some additional details:

- OS = MacOS Sierra 10.12.1
- Compilation: Makefile
- Flags: -g -Wall -Wextra -fbacktrace -fbounds-check -fcheck-array-temporaries
- Optimization: -O2

Example of compilation of the module:

```
# FORCE DEPENDECY BETWEEN MODULE AND OBJECT FILES:
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_core_grids_dts.mod \
: $(OBJ_DIR)/fn_core_grids_dts.o
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_BLD) .. build assumed, <$(MK_COLOR_PURPLE)$@$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> <-- <$(MK_COLOR_PURPLE)$<$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> ... "
@set -e; \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_RED); \
_tic=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(TOUCH) $@; \
_toc=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_NORMAL); \
printf "[$(MK_COLOR_BLUE)%3.3ds$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)]" $$(( $$_toc - $$_tic ))
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_OK)\n"

# COMPILE MODULE:
$(OBJ_DIR)/fn_core_grids_dts.o \
: .concoct/fnode-3d/drv/./src/core/grids/write_fn_core_grids_dts/fn_core_grids_dts.f90 \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_core_nodes_dts.mod \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_infix_fmpi.mod \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_core_grids_common.mod \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_core_exchangers_dts.mod
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_BLD) .. compiling <$(MK_COLOR_YELLOW)$@$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> ... "
@set -e; \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_RED); \
_tic=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MKDIRP) $(OBJ_DIR) $(INCLUDE_DIR); \
$(FC) -c $< -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(FCFT_DIRSRCH_MOD) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(addprefix $(FCFT_DIRSRCH_INCLUDE),$(wildcard $(IDIRS) $(PREPROC_DIR))); \
$(TOUCH) $@; \
_toc=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_NORMAL); \
printf "[$(MK_COLOR_BLUE)%3.3ds$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)]" $$(( $$_toc - $$_tic ))
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_OK)\n"
```

Portion of makefile causing the issue:

```
# FORCE DEPENDECY BETWEEN MODULE AND OBJECT FILES:
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_depot_utils.mod \
: $(OBJ_DIR)/fn_depot_utils.o
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_BLD) .. build assumed, <$(MK_COLOR_PURPLE)$@$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> <-- <$(MK_COLOR_PURPLE)$<$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> ... "
@set -e; \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_RED); \
_tic=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(TOUCH) $@; \
_toc=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_NORMAL); \
printf "[$(MK_COLOR_BLUE)%3.3ds$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)]" $$(( $$_toc - $$_tic ))
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_OK)\n"

# COMPILE MODULE:
$(OBJ_DIR)/fn_depot_utils.o \
: .concoct/fnode-3d/drv/./src/depot/write_fn_depot_utils/fn_depot_utils.f90 \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_depot_common.mod \
$(INCLUDE_DIR)/fn_depot_share.mod
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_BLD) .. compiling <$(MK_COLOR_YELLOW)$@$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)> ... "
@set -e; \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_RED); \
_tic=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MKDIRP) $(OBJ_DIR) $(INCLUDE_DIR); \
$(FC) -c $< -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(FCFT_DIRSRCH_MOD) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(addprefix $(FCFT_DIRSRCH_INCLUDE),$(wildcard $(IDIRS) $(PREPROC_DIR))); \
$(TOUCH) $@; \
_toc=$$($(DATE_EPOCH_SEC)); \
$(MK_COLOR_CMD_SET_NORMAL); \
printf "[$(MK_COLOR_BLUE)%3.3ds$(MK_COLOR_NORMAL)]" $$(( $$_toc - $$_tic ))
@printf "$(MK_DECOR_OK)\n"
```

Note that fn_depot_common.mod includes module fn_core_grids_dts.
It is definitely not an issue related to a missing module not being included where needed.

Comment: How do you compile the code? Makefile, cmake, manually, with what flags, how are you files and modules organized? What is the OS?
Also, do you use finite-scoped derived types? What specific features of Fortran 2003/2008?

Comment: If you have some error, you have to show the command that caused it.